# Mongoid + RoR: Initializing the _id while create()

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I want to get the id from one of my routes

```
POST user/:id
```

and create objects with that params[:id]. I don't have any intention of my application generate/ auto increment the :id when it is used as the _id. 
I tried:

```
    ObjectId("1").str

2015-04-23T14:22:14.888-0700 E QUERY    Error: invalid object id: length
at (shell):1:1.
```

So, I'm guessing it has to do with my extremely short :id (not 12 bytes in length).

A more basic question: How can I convert the :id to a BSON id? I am not particularly interested in making the _id an integer, the BSON string would suit me just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default route to create objects (users in this case) with Rails is `POST /users`. You can customize this route but it's not recommended. So send `id` you want together other data and your `id` will be set.

```
POST /users
{ _id: 123, name: "Maria" }
```

You can convert an integer id to BSON with

```
BSON::ObjectId.from_data(123)
```

But I think that is useless in this case.

Comment: Yes, the conversion wasn't necessary. Thanks.